# How to find servlet class name using url pattern?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using `@WebServlet` annotation in Eclipse.  What is the best way to determine the servlet class name based on a given url-pattern?  Prior to using `WebServlet`, I was able to search for the pattern in web.xml.  But now I'm having to search through the entire project for the url pattern.

A concrete example would be:

> servlet-name: MyServlet
>    url-pattern: /myPattern/*

Let's say I don't know the servlet-name in this case.  And I know the pattern "/myPattern/*".  Besides doing a search for "/myPattern/*", is there anything I can do to quickly look up the name `MyServlet`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all ServlerRegistrations from the context and go through each of them searching match of the given urlPattern. See the following method searchServletRegistrationByUrlPattern().

If you need this often in your project, you can create a Map with urlPattern as key and servletName as value. Similar to createMapOfUrlPatternsToServletNames() + searchServletRegistrationByUrlPattern2().

```
package testingThings;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/myPattern/*")
public class FindServletByUrlPattern extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Search through all ServletRegistrations and return this which is mapped of the given urlPattern. 
     * If no match is found returns null.
     * 
     * @param urlPattern
     * @return ServletRegistration | null
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected ServletRegistration searchServletRegistrationByUrlPattern(String urlPattern) throws IOException {
        Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> servletRegistrations = getServletContext().getServletRegistrations();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> entry : servletRegistrations.entrySet()) {

            ServletRegistration servletRegistration = entry.getValue();
            Collection<String> mappings = servletRegistration.getMappings();

            if (mappings.contains(urlPattern)) {
                return servletRegistration;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Search in a map for given urlPattern. 
     * If no match is found returns null.
     * 
     * @param urlPattern
     * @return ServletRegistration | null
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected ServletRegistration searchServletRegistrationByUrlPattern2(String urlPattern) throws IOException {
        // create urlPattern map
        Map<String, String> urlPatterns = createMapOfUrlPatternsToServletNames();

        String servletName = urlPatterns.get(urlPattern);

        if (servletName== null) {
            return null;
        }

        ServletRegistration servletRegistrationOfSearchedUrlPatternInMap = getServletContext().getServletRegistration(servletName);
        return servletRegistrationOfSearchedUrlPatternInMap;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> createMapOfUrlPatternsToServletNames() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> urlPatters = new TreeMap<String, String>();

        Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> servletRegistrations = getServletContext().getServletRegistrations();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> entry : servletRegistrations.entrySet()) {

            ServletRegistration servletRegistration = entry.getValue();
            Collection<String> mappings = servletRegistration.getMappings();

            for (String urlPattern : mappings) {
                urlPatters.put(urlPattern, entry.getValue().getName());
            }
        }

        return urlPatters;
    }

    protected void showInfoAboutServletRegistration(ServletRegistration servletRegistration, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (servletRegistration == null) {
            response.getWriter().append("there is not servlers for this url-pattern<br>");
        }
        else {
            response.getWriter()
                .append("Servlet Name: ").append(servletRegistration.getName()).append("<br>")
                .append("Servlet Class Name: ").append(servletRegistration.getClassName()).append("<br>")
                .append("Mapping: ").append(Arrays.toString(servletRegistration.getMappings().toArray())).append("<br>")
                .append("<br><br>")
            ;
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // get ServletRegistration of the current servlet through servlet's name
        ServletRegistration servletRegistrationOfCurrentServlet = getServletContext().getServletRegistration(getServletName());
        // show in browser
        showInfoAboutServletRegistration(servletRegistrationOfCurrentServlet, response);

        // search ServletRegistration through url-pattern directly
        String urlPattern = request.getParameter("url-pattern");
        if (urlPattern == null) {
            response.getWriter().append("use a query string parameter 'url-pattern' in order to search servlets for a pattern");
        }
        else {
            ServletRegistration servletRegistrationOfSearchedUrlPattern = searchServletRegistrationByUrlPattern(urlPattern);
            // show in browser
            showInfoAboutServletRegistration(servletRegistrationOfSearchedUrlPattern, response);
        }

        // search ServletRegistration through url-pattern over map
        ServletRegistration servletRegistrationOfSearchedUrlPatternInMap = searchServletRegistrationByUrlPattern2(urlPattern);
        showInfoAboutServletRegistration(servletRegistrationOfSearchedUrlPatternInMap, response);

        showInfoAboutAllServletRegistrations(request, response);
    }

    protected void showInfoAboutAllServletRegistrations(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.getWriter()
            .append("<h3>All ServletRegistrations</h3>")
            .append("<table>")
            .append("<tr><th>")
            .append("servletName:" )
            .append("</th><th>")
            .append("servletClassName:" )
            .append("</th><th>")
            .append("Mapping:" )
            .append("</th></tr>")
        ;

        Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> servletRegistrations = request.getServletContext().getServletRegistrations();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> entry : servletRegistrations.entrySet()) {

            ServletRegistration servlet = entry.getValue();
            String servletName = servlet.getName();
            String servletClassName = servlet.getClassName();
            Collection<String> mappings = servlet.getMappings();

            response.getWriter()
                .append("<tr><td>")
                .append(servletName)
                .append("</td><td>")
                .append(servletClassName)
                .append("</td><td>")
                .append(Arrays.toString(mappings.toArray()))
                .append("</td></tr>")
            ;

        }
    }

}
```

JavaDocs

- [ServletContext.getServletRegistration(String servletName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistration-java.lang.String-)
- [ServletContext.getServletRegistrations()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistrations--)

Comment: This is not quite what I'm looking for.  But thank you!  I was hoping for a method that doesn't involve coding up a custom solution.  Right now I'm going by a self-made rule that the urlPattern must match the servlet name.  It is working for now.